# How to handle the event correctly OVERFLOW in watchService

Tags: java, api, overflow

When I copy 200-250 files to a folder everything happens perfectly. But if I throw 1000 files, an error occurs in random order - or rather, the key gets the event `event.kind() == OVERFLOW`. And then I get the NPE in the code. Here is the question of how to do it correctly, so as not to lose the keys, and correctly check all the files. Thanks

```
while (true) {

            WatchKey key;

            try {
                key = watchService.take();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {

                //if key=overflow , fileName = null....

                Path fileName = ((WatchEvent<Path>) event).context();
                File newFile = new File(directory + fileName.getFileName()); 
                ListAttributes contextLoad = dataManager.load(dbUpdateWorker.contLoad(newFile));


                if (event.kind() == ENTRY_CREATE) {
```

I saw a similar topic on the forum, but did not understand how the answer implements...